# Tensorflow object detection: neither model_main.py nor train.py work anymore

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

**train.py**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/legacy/train.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import framework as contrib_framework
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

**module_main.py**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 26, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 40, in <module>
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I can't even export my model from checkpoint to inference graph because of the same error.

**export_inference_graph.py**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/export_inference_graph.py", line 108, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/exporter.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.quantize.python import graph_matcher
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

All three files worked perfectly up until today. Training worked with TF 1.15 and 2.1.0. I was using Colab with Python 3.6 and GPU training. I also could not find any substantial changes recently in the github repo of tensorflow.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Can you please provide how you import this tensorflow.contrib and other relevant information that will help us troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: `Tf.contrib` is moved out of Tf 2.0. You need to use only Tf 1.15. If you want to use latest Tf version convert your model to Tf 2.x compatible by following migration guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).  contrib api is deprecated, know more about [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md). Thanks!